# How can I write information to two database tables from one "if "statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I wish to post the users entered information into two different tables in the same data base. However my code does not seem to work, it only writes into the second table that I have asked it to write to. Why wont it write to the first table as well?

```
if ($_POST['entereddetail']) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO firsttable (thedetail, date)
VALUES ('". $_POST['entereddetail'] ."', NOW())";

$sql = "INSERT INTO secondtable (thedetail, code, branch, user, date)
VALUES ('". $_POST['entereddetail'] ."','". $_POST['codedetail'] ."', '', '', NOW())";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
   }      
}
```

I know my code could be subject to SQL injection. I am only learning the basics at the moment and then I deal with security after as I am only new to SQL and databases. My branch and users field are also left blank as I will be dealing with them later.

Comment: _“Why wont it write to the first table as well?”_ – because you are _sending_ only one query to the database. Other than that, you are only overwriting the string content in a variable called $sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're overwriting your `$sql` variable.

Adapt your code like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO firsttable (thedetail, date)
VALUES ('". $_POST['entereddetail'] ."', NOW());";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO secondtable (thedetail, code, branch, user, date)
VALUES ('". $_POST['entereddetail'] ."','". $_POST['codedetail'] ."', '', '', NOW());";
```

**Notice**: If you look closely, you'll see a `;` at the of the sql-statements. The `.=` will combine the two `$sql` variables into one string of two MySQL-statements.

Comment: @Flosculus I assume, your comment refers to the version where I just posted the first sentence, right ... "mate"? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your only executing the second query...

```
if ($_POST['entereddetail']) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO firsttable (thedetail, date)
            VALUES ('". $_POST['entereddetail'] ."', NOW())";
if ( mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO secondtable (thedetail, code, branch, user, date)
               VALUES ('". $_POST['entereddetail'] ."','". $_POST['codedetail'] ."', '', '', NOW())";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        echo "Records inserted successfully.";
    } else{
       echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
   }      
}
else{
       echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
   }
```